# Is it possible to access string-indexed getter with Spring XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans, getter

Is there a notion of "string-indexed" getters in spring context setup XML language? Suppose I have `Person` getter with the following prototype:

```
class Person {
   Person getRelative(String relativeName);
   ...
}
```

Can I access it with something like

```
<bean id="Bob" class="Person"/>

<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" ref="Bob.relative.father"/>
</bean>
```

saying that Bob's father is the owner of Barnyard company.

The `Company` prototype is like follows:

```
class Company {
   Person getOwner();
   void setOwner(Person value);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring-El for this:

```
<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" value="#{Bob.getRelative('father')"/>
</bean>
```