# Refering properties of properties in Spring XML at RHS?

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

There are compound property names in Spring XML but I can't find compound property values.

Suppose I have `Person` getter with the following prototype:

```
class Person {
   Person getFather();
   void setFather(Person value);
   String getAge();
   void setAge(String value);
   ...
}
```

The `Company` prototype is like follows:

```
class Company {
   Person getOwner();
   void setOwner(Person value);
   ...
}
```

Can I connect these with something like

```
<bean id="Bob" class="Person"/>

<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" ref="Bob.father"/>
</bean>
```

Above does not works saying "no bean with `Bob.father` id".

The following also does not work

```
<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" value="Bob.father"/>
</bean>
```

saying can't convert `String` to `Person`.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

Suppose I want to set age of company owner. Apparently I should write this:

```
<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" value="#{Bob.father}"/>
   <property name="owner.age" value="38"/>
</bean>
```

Isn't this a bad design when I CAN use properties of properties at LEFT but CANNOT do the same at RIGHT??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring EL will work here also, even more concise than the question you had [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823332/is-it-possible-to-access-string-indexed-getter-with-spring-xml) -

```
<bean id="Barnyard" class="Company">
   <property name="owner" value="#{Bob.father}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: By I don't understand why left hand side works without EL, while right hand side does not.

Comment: When you specify `<bean id="barnyard"..> <property name="owner" value="..">` essentially what Spring is doing is calling on the setter on the `owner` property this way,  `barnyard.setOwner(..)`, now if you want to refer to another bean you can use `<propery name="owner" ref=../>`, however if you want to resolve some field within another bean then the only option is something like Spring-El which can evaluate expressions like the one defined above to resolve  `getFather` of `Bob` bean. more details here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: By I CAN write `<property name="owner.age" value="35"/>` i.e. I CAN refer to properties of properties at the LEFT. While EL is required to do the SAME at the RIGHT. I guess it is bad design.